# How to deserialize decimal property with precision

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, decimal

In my WEb Api I am returning json like this:

```
  class Test
  {
    public decimal Dec { get; set; }
  }

  Test test = new Test() { Dec = 1.00m };
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
  return json;
```

Currently, the json is

```
{
  "Dec": 1.00
}
```

I am trying to test it like this:

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var decimalValue = dictionary["Dec"]; // I am expecting 1.00 but it is 1
```

It is getting 1 instead of 1.00. But when I do:

```
        var myTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
        var decimalValue = myTest.Dec; // It is 1.00
```

It is getting 1.00. But the problem is I cannot use Test class on my tests. Question is why after deserializing it to dictionary it is 1? Should I create a new class like 'Test' or is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What is `decimalValue.GetType()`?

Comment: @mjwills, oops, it becomes as Double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Setting `FloatParseHandling` to `Decimal` in `JsonSerializerSettings` solved my problem:

```
    var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal });
    var decimalValue = dictionary["Dec"];
```